# MYSQL `SELECT` Multiple tables colums with `JOIN` and `USING` but not `*`

Tags: mysql

Okay, here's what I'm doing with a MYSQL SELECT query.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
JOIN CustomerDetails USING (`Customer_ID`)
JOIN CustomerNotes USING (`Customer_ID`)
WHERE Customer_ID ='1'
```

This is fine and working like expected. What I would like to do is something along the lines of...

```
SELECT Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.CompanyName, Customers.ContactPerson
FROM Customers
JOIN CustomerDetails.Customer_ID, CustomerDetails.MinPurchase, CustomerDetails.Discount FROM CustomerDetails USING (`Customer_ID`)
JOIN CustomerNotes.Customer_ID, CustomerNotes.CustNotes FROM CustomerNotes USING (`Customer_ID`)
WHERE Customer_ID = '1'
```

That the idea I'm looking to reach here. I want to be able to tell the query what to get instead of `*`. 
I'm using 3 tables `Customers` `CustomerDetails` `CustomerNotes`. Any ideas??? Thanks!

Comment: All you need to do is change the SELECT list from * to the three columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 

    Customers.Customer_ID, 
    Customers.CompanyName, 
    Customers.ContactPerson,

    CustomerDetails.Customer_ID, 
    CustomerDetails.MinPurchase, 
    CustomerDetails.Discount,

    CustomerNotes.Customer_ID, 
    CustomerNotes.CustNotes

FROM Customers
JOIN CustomerDetails USING (`Customer_ID`)
JOIN CustomerNotes USING (`Customer_ID`)
WHERE Customers.Customer_ID = '1'
```

You'd have to use "as" within each Customer_ID because they are the same. But I see no reason why you select Customer_ID twice. Just delete the duplicates. Final one:

```
SELECT 

    Customers.Customer_ID, 
    Customers.CompanyName, 
    Customers.ContactPerson,

    CustomerDetails.MinPurchase, 
    CustomerDetails.Discount,

    CustomerNotes.CustNotes

FROM Customers
JOIN CustomerDetails USING (`Customer_ID`)
JOIN CustomerNotes USING (`Customer_ID`)
WHERE Customers.Customer_ID = '1'
```

Comment: This is the One! Thanks genesis you got it. I see what I messed up on. I was making it to complicated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You put all of the fields you want in the place where the star is now:

```
SELECT Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.CompanyName, Customers.ContactPerson,
CustomerDetails.MinPurchase, CustomerDetails.Discount, CustomerNotes.CustNotes
FROM Customers
JOIN CustomerDetails USING (`Customer_ID`)
JOIN CustomerNotes USING (`Customer_ID`)
WHERE Customer_ID ='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to select all the data from one table, or specific columns from each?

```
   SELECT Customers.* FROM Customers
   JOIN CustomerDetails USING (`Customer_ID`)
   JOIN CustomerNotes USING (`Customer_ID`)
   WHERE Customer_ID ='1'
```